# Unable to import a .fbx file properly in blender and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

I am learning blender so i was trying to import a model[laptop] downloaded from a website to see how it works. I downloaded a .fbx file and tried to import it in blender but it gave wrong results like not showing keyboard buttons for a laptop.

It would be helpful of anybody who can guide me in importing it properly so that i can use that file and work on that file and 3d model and explore Blender more.

**Link -: https://sketchfab.com/models/7ba340f1ca824c25b9e488b6cf6ef523#**

The link mentioned above has the model. Can someone help me in importing it step by step properly in blender and Unity as both support .fbx files. Currently the model i imported shows a pink colored keyboard without any buttons visible

I am completely new to Blender so the help would be appreciated a lot. Hoping for the help.

Comment: No, it's a serious point. If you write in all-caps here, or don't otherwise take the time to write well-formatted posts, you will get downvoted. It is off-topic anyway, since it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried to import from sketchfab, however if you just want to import model just for learning purposes you can import (download file) from blender site.

Talking about unity, best thing you can do is open unity and drag your .blend file into editor, Unity will import it and create every thing you will need to use your model as gameobject. I suggest you yo try this and ask and specific question about this because this workflow trends to fail in some scenarios.

BTW: you said your model shows pink keyboard, maybe your material or texture are missing. To solve this you can create material object in Unity and drag you texture to albedo property.